How Pyth is able to update each feed contract every block?
How they garantee the TX successful landing?
Running their own validator would increase the certainty of landing the tx?
Looks like they are sending the transaction here.

I can't speak for the specifics, but if they are running their own staked validator, they will get more connections to the network, making it easier to land transactions. They also add priority fees, which also helps get the transaction in.
